# Data URI colors are off

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, data-uri

I've got a blob of an image that is stored in an Oracle database, I need to take the blob and display it as an image on a web page. To grab the blob, I'm doing an AJAX call like this:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/rest/api/summaryWithPicture/001',
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(result) {
            var dataURI = result.picture.pictureThumbnail;

            $(".profileImage").attr("src", "data:image/jpeg;base64," + dataURI);

        }
    });
```

This displays the image, however the colors are wrong. The image below shows the original picture (left) next to what is displayed on the web page (right)

[image: Imgur]

Comment: Have you confirmed that the image is correctly stored in the database? If you go to the REST url in your browser does it look like that also?

Comment: What's the colorspace of the image? Wouldn't be surprised if it was CMYK.